# CSS3 keyframes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, css-animations

Is it possible using animation keyframes in JavaScript? If your answer is no, please tell me how can I use codes like this?
I wrote my jQuery plugin but I don't know how can I use keyframes.
`animate()` doesn't work (translateZ...)

Comment: define classes in css and then use addClass removeClass by jquery!

Comment: use classes per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568623/trigger-css3-keyframes-using-jquery

Comment: I want to change keyframes values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to [research css3 keyframes](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp) then maybe make a small example for yourself to get a basic understanding.
[jQuery.Keyframes](https://github.com/jQueryKeyframes/jQuery.Keyframes) allows you to generate css3 keyframes and attach events on the fly with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a third party library that allows for a variety of different translations.

http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

If that still doesnt so what you need you can refer to this question

[Set Webkit Keyframes Values Using Javascript Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342494/set-webkit-keyframes-values-using-javascript-variable)

which will show you how to inject rules into the CSSOM dynamically using jQuery

[Somewhat working fiddle for Firefox](http://jsfiddle.net/RHhBz/333/)

uses

```
@keyframes rotate {
    0% {-moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);}
    100% {-moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);}
}
```

and other vendor prefix specifics. There seems to be some kind of problem where sometimes the animation will trigger but other times it wont. Haven t been able to figure out why

Comment: First link broke my styles
tnx

Comment: Did you include it properly

Comment: Yep
Before include: http://kanakh.com/upload/uploads/13780157531.jpg
After include: http://kanakh.com/upload/uploads/13780157532.jpg
Just write this: <script src="../jquery.transit.min.js"></script>

Comment: Ahh ok i would say the problem is that the library is most likely applying translate3d(0, 0, 0) to all the elements to prepare for transitions. Look into the second half of my answer if that is not acceptable.

Comment: I don't know how remove webkit http://jsfiddle.net/russelluresti/RHhBz/2/ 
when remove all the webkit it doesn't work in firefox

Comment: you need to use the vendor prefix `-moz` for firefox